# Get user name in Razor Pages from HttpContext: where to put the code

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am new to Razor Pages. I have just one page, I have Index.cshtml and Index.cshtml.cs with

`public class IndexModel : PageModel`

There is also `_Layout.cshtml`.

I need to get username from `HttpContext Header.` and show username in `_Layout.cshtml` (there is navigation bar).

But I do not get where is the best place to put this code in Razor Pages?
I cannot put it into `Index.cshtml.cs OnGet`, because I need in Layout, at least I think so.

---

This is outside this question, but FYI I use Azure Easy Auth and from documentation (and also other non Razor Pages projects) I see that `HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-ID"]` would contain Name I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the current `HttpContext` inside of a Razor Page using the [`Context`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.razorpage.context) property:

```html
<p>@Context.Request.Headers["X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-ID"]</p>
```

This approach is documented in [Use HttpContext from a Razor view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context#use-httpcontext-from-a-razor-view).

Answer (score 1):

`@Context` is not available in razor page in .NET 6

But you can use `@Request.HttpContext`